# RequireJS : nested require calls

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have a scenario where I have nested require() calls to load up different modules.

Is there a way for me to ensure that all the require() invocation and all its child require() invocations are fully loaded before the callback function is called?

Is there a way to specify that require() calls are synchronous?

```
function someFunction(callback) {

  //top level require
  require([...], function(...) {

     //nested require
     require([...], function(...) {
     });

     //nested require
     require([...], function(...) {
     });

  });

  callback();
};
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using dependencies?

Comment: Yes.  However we're trying to separate our stuff into separate files. For example the code above is in FileA.js. FileB.js calls someFunction() with its callback.  However it's callback has a dependency on some settings that occur in the require() callbacks of FileA.js.  Problem is that the asynchronous nature of require means that the callback is executed before it's dependencies in require() is set.

Answer (score 3):

You need to execute the `callback` in the last `require(...)` function:

```
function someFunction(callback) {
   require(['somemodule'], function(someModule) {
     // do stuff with someModule...

     // execute callback
     callback(); 
   });
}
```

What you also could do is to specify your [dependencies with the define function](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#defdep).

Example:

```
define('somemodule', ['somedependency'], function(someDependency) {
   // return somemodule
   return {
     someProperty: someDependency.getProperty();
   };
});

function someFunction(callBack) {
   var someModule = require('somemodule');   
   var foo = someModule.someProperty;

   return callBack(foo);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to make `require` call sync. Make it CommonJS style:

```
var module = require('modulepath')
```

So, if you would **NOT** need a factory funciton in your nested require calls, you could "sync" the require calls that way... But since you do you are out of luck.

AMD style `requre(depsArray, factoryFn)` is exactly like pushing your code into a parallel thread. There is no way to make it "sync" but you can use "semaphores" to coordinate the result.

The answer to your question also greatly depends on what nested A and nested B consume. If they depend on some product from top require like so you absolutely must use "threaded semaphores" and cannot just push nested require calls into named define calls:

```
function someFunction(callback) {

  var resultOfOuterCode = someResultOfCalculations

  //top level require
  require([...], function(...) {

    var resultOfTopRequireCode = someOtherResultOfCalculations

    var semaphore = {
      'count': 2 // represents the number of thread that need to be "done" before 
      , 'callback':callback // this callback is fired.
      , 'checkIfLast': function(){
        this.count -= 1
        if (!this.count) {
          // count is now 0 - time to run our callback
          this.callback()
        }
      }
    }

    //nested require A
    require([...], function(...) {
      // using resultOfTopRequireCode // <-- !!!! this is important part
      ...
      semaphore.checkIfLast()
    });

    //nested require B
    require([...], function(...) {
      // using resultOfTopRequireCode // <-- !!!! this is important part
      semaphore.checkIfLast()
    });

  });

};
```

In other words, just think of require(dependsArray, factoryFn) as "threads" and apply your understanding of using threads to it.